# Entity Framework Code First no database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to create a DB using EF code first.
I did the following:

- Created the classes
- Created a data context using said classes
- I used parameterless constructor on context class with `:base("connectionstring")`
- I opened the Nuget Manager console and i typed the commands:

*enable-migrations*

*add-migrations mydatabase*

*update-database*

After doing this the folder with the migration files appeared in the solution explorer but the Database still doesn't appear in my SQL Server Management Studio

Below is the code:

**1.Classes**

```
public class Kid
{      
    public int KidId { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("School")]
public class School
{
    [Key]
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public List<Kid> Kids { get; set; }

}

public class SchoolContext:DbContext
{
    public  SchoolContext() : base("SchoolContext") { }
    public DbSet<Kid> Kid { get; set; }
    public DbSet<School> School { get; set; }
}
```

**2.Main**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SchoolContext myDb = new SchoolContext();
        Kid mykid = new Kid { Age = 14, KidId = 2, Name = "Adrian" };
        Kid mykid2 = new Kid { Age = 16, KidId = 3, Name = "Adriansan" };
        School mySchool = new School { Kids = new List<Kid>{ mykid, mykid2 }, SchoolId = 73, SchoolName = "Iovan Ducici" };
        myDb.Kid.Add(mykid);
        myDb.School.Add(mySchool);
        myDb.SaveChanges();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I suspect there's something to be done in the App.config file which has a connectionString tag which is empty but I don't know what it has to be completed.

Comment: Have you run your code? Once you access the context the database will be created depending on your [initializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: I have not used an initializer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you need to have a connection string in the app config that knows 'where' is your database created at.  A context is just a blueprint to create the database that 'SchoolContext' should be referencing a connection string in an app config or similar to an actual project that runs the EF Code First

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="SchoolContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=.;Database=SchoolContext;Integrated Security=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

If you do not have this it will most likely not work.  And since you do a lot of stuff manually with EF code first it may not show up.  Or it may assume an MS default database which handles connections differently than MS SQL or it may be SQL Express.

I took this tutorial from this site a while back and it is fantastic for learning the ins and outs of the basics for EF Code First: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much sir  for explanation and tutorial.I added the tag in the App.config ,i set the Server name and it worked like a charm ! Thank you very much. I must ask is it the same if you want to to create a web application using MVC? You add the tag in the web config file and the rest is the same?

Comment: Correct, any time you need to reference the project that has code first IT should have the app config if it is desktop code like Winforms, WPF or a console app.  For ASP.NET or similar web it needs to be in the web config.  If you are happy with the answer please mark it as complete.